# Clear Type problem in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, cleartype

I try to tune ClearType in Windows 7 x64 using the **ClearType Text Tuner**. I can choose whatever options I want on the first 3 pages, but on the last page, whatever I choose is reverted as soon as I click finish. Next time I run the tuner I can see that the second option is selected, not the option that I wanted (the last one).

Has anybody else found this odd behavior?

Comment: I'm also experiencing this... :(

Answer (score -1):

I just installed ClearType again on my machine today and received the warning that there are issues with this software and Vista.  I imagine you received that same error.

There is an advanced tab on the start screen that should give you all the options on one page instead of the interview style of the program.  You might want to try that.

Comment: The ClearType Text Tuner is built into Windows 7 now.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but as Jared said, I was talking about the builtin ClearType Tuner from Win7 x64.