# ClearType settings are not saving properly

Tags: windows-7

On Windows 7 (64 bit, if that matters), I use the ClearType Text Tuner to adjust the smoothing of type, and after answering all the "choose the one you like best" panels, it looks like everything has completed successfully.  But when I open the control panel again, my choices are not the current ones, and when I restart the computer, the type is noticeably worse.

What's going on?

Comment: Sorry: this should have been on superuser, where the same question has already been asked: http://superuser.com/questions/49732/clear-type-problem-in-windows-7

Comment: No worries, we'll migrate it so someone can close as duplicate.  It may help someone find the answer in the futere.